A question on IR divergence in Peskin-Schroeder chapter 6
In equation 6.64 of Peskin Schroeder, it computes $f_{\text{IR}}(q^2)$ in the limit $-q^2\to\infty$. Now, if we try to simplify the integral:
\begin{align}
f_{\text{IR}}(q^2) &=\int_0^1d\xi\;\frac{m^2-q^2/2}{m^2-q^2\xi(1-\xi)}-1\tag{6.62}\\
&= \int_0^1d\xi\;\frac{m^2}{m^2-q^2\xi(1-\xi)}-1 + \int_0^1d\xi\;\frac{-q^2/2}{m^2-q^2\xi(1-\xi)}
\end{align}
Then, PS writes:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1d\xi\;\frac{-q^2/2}{m^2-q^2\xi(1-\xi)} & \simeq \frac{1}{2}\int_0 d\xi\;\frac{-q^2}{m^2-q^2\xi} + \text{(equal contribution from } \xi\approx 1)\\
&= \log\left(\frac{-q^2}{m^2}\right).\tag{6.64}
\end{align}
I do not understand how the first term in $f_{\text{IR}}(q^2)$ is zero. i.e., $$\int_0^1d\xi\;\frac{m^2}{m^2-q^2\xi(1-\xi)}-1=0$$
I can go to the next step:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1d\xi\;\frac{m^2}{m^2-q^2\xi(1-\xi)}-1 &= \int_0^1d\xi\;\frac{m^2}{m^2-q^2\xi(1-\xi)}-\int_0^1d\xi \\
&= \int_0^1d\xi\;\left(\frac{m^2}{m^2-q^2\xi(1-\xi)}-1\right)\\
&=\int_0^1d\xi\;\frac{q^2\xi(1-\xi)}{m^2-q^2\xi(1-\xi)}
\end{align}
After this, I have no idea how this goes to $0$.
Secondly, how the limit is taken in equation (6.64)? Is the upper limit of the first term taken to be $<1$? But then how to justify the second term?

Four lines after eq. (6.63), Peskin and Schroeder say explictly: "To gain a better understanding of the divergence, let us evaluate the coefficient of the divergent logarithm, $f_{\rm IR}(q^2)$, in the limit $-q^2 \to \infty$. In this limit., ...". So, your first term tends to $-1$, being much smaller than the dominant term in the limit under consideration.
Concerning your second question, the relevant contributions in (6.64) come from the integration regions near $\xi\simeq 0$ and $\xi \simeq 1$, explaining their approach.
Edit: Explicit determination of the integral $$I(-m^2/q^2)= \int\limits_0^1 \!d\xi \frac{-q^2/2}{-q^2\xi (1-\xi)+m^2}=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^1 \! \frac{d\xi}{\xi(1-\xi)-m^2/q^2}$$ (corresponding to eq. (6.64) of Peskin & Schroeder) in the limit $-q^2/m^2 \to \infty$ (or, equivalently, in the limit $-m^2/q^2 \to 0$). Obviously the integral diverges (is undefined) for $m^2/q^2=0$ because of the singularities of the integrand at $\xi=0$ and $\xi=1$. For $-m^2/q^2 \gt 0$, the integral is finite, but the dominant contributions come from the regions near $\xi=0$ and $\xi=1$, where the integrand attains its maxima. As we are not interested in the full result for $I(-m^2/q^2)$ but only in its asymptotic expansion for $-m^2/q^2 \downarrow 0$, we split the domain of integration into three parts, $[0, \epsilon]$, $[\epsilon, 1-\epsilon]$ and $[1-\epsilon,1]$ with $0 \lt \epsilon \lt \!\!\lt 1$. The contribution from the middle interval is subdominant in the limit $-m^2/q^2 \downarrow 0$ and we are left with $$I(-m^2/q^2)=\frac{1}{2} \int\limits_0^\epsilon\frac{d\xi}{\xi(1-\xi)-m^2/q^2} + \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{1-\epsilon}^1 \frac{d\xi}{\xi(1-\xi)-m^2/q^2}+\ldots,$$ where the dots refer to subdominant terms. Because of $0 \le \xi \le \epsilon \lt \!\!\lt 1$ in the left integral, we can futher approximate $\xi (1-\xi)$ by $\xi$ (the difference in the result is again subdominant). Analogously, we replace $\xi(1-\xi)$ by $1-\xi$ in the right integral followed by a transformation of variables $1-\xi \to \xi$, leading to the final result $$I(-m^2/q^2) = \int\limits_0^\epsilon \frac{d\xi}{\xi-m^2/q^2}=\log\left(\frac{-q^2}{m^2}\right)+\ldots$$ in agreement with the second line of eq. (6.64) in Peskin & Schroeder.

I didn't quite understand the answer to the second question. Can you elaborate a bit more on why regions near $\xi\simeq 0$ and $\xi\simeq 1$ only gives the relevant contributions.

@SoumyajitDatta See my edit.
